# react components not rendering with routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using the latest version of react router. When I am using routes in my component, They are not rendering anything but When I remove the routes and use simply the component they are working fine. Not able to understand what is going wrong

This do not work  and is not rendering anything on "/" or `http://localhost:3000/`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Users from "./user/pages/Users";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Navigate to="/" />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is rendering and working fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Users from "./user/pages/Users";

function App() {
  return <Users />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think the problem is, you are redirecting using Navigate to "/" always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Users from "./user/pages/Users";
import Profiles from "./Profiles" // this is dummy

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false)
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Users />}/>
        <Route path="/profiles" element={state ? <Profiles /> : <Navigate to="/" />} /> 
        {/* so you redirect only if your state is false */}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks but what if i want to redirect someone

Comment: use Navigate when you need to redirect under some condition, let me update the answer with a such case

Comment: I updated my answer with a dummy test case, you can check

Answer (score 0):

It is because, You din't provide which element to render in `Route`. It has to be mentioned like `element={<Users />}`. So try like below,

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Users from "./user/pages/Users";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
     <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Users />} />
      <Navigate to="/" />
     </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: no still not rendering. i copy pasted the exact code but its not working

Comment: Please let me know your React Router Dom version

Comment: no still not working

Comment: Please let me know your React Router Dom version

Comment: "react-router-dom": 6.3.0

Comment: Check you console and let me know if you are getting any errors...

Comment: no errors its compiled successfully

Comment: Check whether you are have imported the `Users` component properly...

Comment: Remove `<Navigate to="/" />` and provide route like `<Route path="/" element={<Users />} index />`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs, all Route components should be placed inside a Routes component, which is nested inside the BrowserRouter.

Also, I noticed you use Navigate everytime, even when you are already at the index path. I think this may cause a problem...

So, with that in mind, Change your code to

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Users from "./user/pages/Users";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route index element={<Users />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: no this is nto working.

Comment: Could you go to your package.json and tell us the exact version of react-router-dom you're using?

Comment: "react-router-dom": 6.3.0,

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component renders its content on the `element` prop as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, the only valid child of the `Route` component is another `Route` component for the case of nesting routes. The `Users` component should be moved to the `element` prop.

Also, to render a redirect to a default route, the `Navigate` component should ***also*** be rendered on a generic route.

## Solution

- Move `Users` component onto route's `element` prop.
- Move the `Navigate` component into a generic route and pass the `replace` prop so issue a redirect.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" element={<Users />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```